# How can I set different bandwidth limits for multiple terminals using linux tc?

Tags: linux, tc, bandwidth, gateway

How to set different speed for different terminals?

In my case:

Total bandwidth is 100Mbits/s.
No more than 100 terminals.
I want each terminal use no more than 2Mbits/s or 3Mbits/s bindwidth
I have tried like this:

1. for init setup

   sudo tc qdisc add dev eth0 root handle 1: htb default 10
   sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 100mbit
   sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 1mbit
2. for each terminal

   sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:x htb rate 2mbit
   sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.168.0.x flowid 1:x

or

```
sudo tc class add dev eth0 parent 1:1 classid 1:x htb rate 3mbit
sudo tc filter add dev eth0 protocol ip parent 1: prio 1 u32 match ip dst 192.168.0.y flowid 1:y
```

So I need one class and one filter for each terminal. However if there are 1000 or even more terminals, I need to setup more classes and filters. Is there any better way?

Comment: what are the 3 sentences in aid of?